# How to convert varchar to int/float in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My data is coming from `mysql` table.

`id,revenue,cost,state` are `varchar` columns.

- I need to do get_dummies(one hot encoding) for my categorical variable that is state only
- if its reading directly from `csv`(pd.read_csv) I am getting dtypes of `id,revenue,cost` as int/float and `state` as object

My Question is how to convert object to int64/float if its numeric and object for category variable

- There is a chance of some `strange` like ?,- character might appear in revenue, still i want this column to be numeric

What I have done

- To fix this right now change the `varchar` to int in the database directly and issue got fixed

But i need to do in pandas

`df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(df)`  still my int/float columns such as `id,revenue,cost` is not changing dtype

Comment: when you do a `fillna(df)` after coercing the invalid numerics, this will fill the nan with invalid numerics hence resulting in dtype `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first is necesarry test dtypes after `pd.read_csv`:

```
print (df.dtypes)
```

Then converting columns to numeric, but cannot replace missing values to original, because get mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
cols = ['id','revenue','cost']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```